# Why is shutdown faster from the command line than from the GUI?

Tags: command-line, shutdown, gui

I am learning Linux system administration and I noticed that if I do

```
sudo systemctl poweroff
```

on my Ubuntu Xenial, it carries out the command far faster than it would if I did the same using the shutdown button from the GUI.

From the little I have done with Linux, this seems to be the case with most commands.

My understanding (I could be wrong being a system admin in the making) is that the off button also calls the `systemctl poweroff` command. This I inferred from the way the `apt` tool works as it calls the underlying `dpkg` when running a task.

I would think the time difference shouldn't be very noticeable but it is.

Comment: In general, GUI introduces a lot of overhead, which is not very surprising. Also, any linux distro is much more then just linux.

Comment: @mikewhatever, yes i know that GUI has a lot of overhead but when I execute the `command` from the terminal it also sends a `shutdown signal` to the GUI. I would have thought the time difference wouldn't be much. The exact mechanism for this is what I desire to know.

Comment: @muru I mistakenly did that it was not intentional. Didn't know what to do when i got a notice to the edit done earlier. I would kindly revert to the edit.

Comment: @muru, please how do I accept the edit done, or do I simple leave it as is?

Comment: I have rolled it back to my revision, and retracted the downvote. You can leave it as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know...

```
$> poweroff
```

This kills all processes instantly, whereas pressing the `poweroff button` in the UI first checks if all ***GUI*** windows/processes are ready to be shut down (e.g.: if a text editor hasn't saved, ...). After that it kills the desktop environment (window manager, x server, and so on...).

Comment: Thanks I understand it now. As the _poweroff_ button does a lot of checks before shutdown.